# Linux, modified files time stamp differs from current time

Tags: linux, datetime, timestamp

I'm having trouble with the modification date of modified files.
The problem is whenever I modify a file the modification date is set a few minutes ahead of the current date

```
touch a  
ls -l a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2012-09-02 10:49 a

date
Sun Sep  2 10:46:07 IRDT 2012
```

This seems to be causing trouble when I want to do a *make*

```
make[1]: *** File `Makefile' has modification time in the future
```

This is on a debian system which I connect to using ssh and I have no root access.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a good bet the file is located on a file system mounted over the network and the real time clock on the file server is a few minutes ahead of your local system's time.

Comment: Tell your sysadmin about NTP.

Answer (score 1):

If your sysadmin can't fix it any time soon, and you don't have root, you could just manually touch the file with a specific date (-t) instead.